# perform segue swift 4

Tags: json, swift, post, segue

I am trying to validate the login of a user with my database. When the login button is pressed I want to say whether a segue will happen or no based on the info returned back from the database. I start with a variable decision set to true initially and if the I can't validate the user I want to set it to false and prevent segue. This is the code that I have, but there is a problem with it. The return statement at the end is always true. What happens basically is the return statement at the end after .resume() get called first before the response is returned from the database. Can someone clarify why this is happening

```
 override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String,sender: 
 Any?) -> Bool
 {
             var decision = true
            let url = URL(string:"http://192.23.25.98/login/php")
            var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let body = "UserNameLogIn=\(userName.text!.lowercased())&PasswordLogIn=\(passWord.text!.lowercased())"
            request.httpBody=body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
                if (error == nil)
               {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        do
                        {
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? Dictionary<AnyHashable,AnyObject>
                            guard let parseJson = json else{
                                print ("error parsing")
                                return
                            }
                            let status = parseJson["status"]
                            if (status != nil)
                            {
                                if (parseJson.count>3)
                                {
                                    decision = true

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    decision = false


                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                            print("error: \(error)")
                        }
                    })
                }
                else
                {
                    decision = false
                }
                }.resume()
    return decision
}
```

Comment: You can't perform an asynchronous operation to return a value from `shouldPerformSegue`.

Comment: I tried DispatchQueue.main.sync and it still doesnot work

Comment: That doesn't matter, the data task is still asynchronous.

Comment: sorry could you elaborate further. you mean that  URLSession.shared.dataTask is always asynchronous ?

Comment: Yes it is. You need to make the determination in a split second without doing any network access.

Comment: @rmaddy can you clarify further if you dont mind ?. I Dont get what do you mean by "You need to make the determination in a split second without doing any network access"

Comment: Nothing much more complicated than `return someCondition` such as `return someBool` or `return someArray.count > 0` or whatever makes sense.

Comment: so if the the user enters an invalid password I wont be able to validate it before receiving the data response right because this function will always be true. How can I go around that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than initiating the segue on the tap of the button and trying to capture an asynchronous process within `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`, you instead should just have the button define a `@IBAction` that performs the validation request and programmatically initiates the segue if it succeeded.

Thus:

1. Remove the segue from the button.
2. Add segue between the view controllers by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the view controller icon in the bar above the first scene to the second scene:

   [image]
3. Select the segue and give it a name in the attributes inspector:

   [image]
4. Having removed the segue from the button, you can now hook up your button to an `@IBAction` method:

   [image]
5. Your login action should [`performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) when you finish your validation logic:

   ```
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextSceneSegue", sender: self)
   ```

   E.g.

   ```
   @IBAction func didTapLoginButton(_ sender: Any) {
       let url = URL(string:"http://192.23.25.98/login/php")
       var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
       request.httpMethod = "POST"
       request.httpBody = ["UserNameLogIn": useridTextField.text!, "PasswordLogIn": passwordTextField.text!]
           .map { $0.key + "=" + $0.value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)! }
           .joined(separator: "&")
           .data(using: .utf8)

       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               guard let data = data, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200 ..< 300) ~= httpResponse.statusCode, error == nil else {
                   // handle basic network errors here
                   return
               }

               guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] else {
                   // handle json parsing errors here
                   return
               }

               if json["status"] == nil  {
                   // handle missing status here
                   return
               }

               guard json.count > 3 else {
                   // handle incorrect count here
                   return
               }

               self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextSceneSegue", sender: self)
           }
       }.resume()
   }
   ```
6. Note, I percent encode the values in the body of the request. Passwords, in particular, might contain reserved characters. And I don't make the mistake of using [`.urlQueryAllowed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1416698-urlqueryallowed), but instead used `.urlQueryValueAllowed`, in which I pulled out a few reserved characters:

   ```
   extension CharacterSet {

       /// Returns the character set for characters allowed in the individual parameters within a query URL component.
       ///
       /// The query component of a URL is the component immediately following a question mark (?).
       /// For example, in the URL `http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1#jumpLink`, the query
       /// component is `key1=value1`. The individual parameters of that query would be the key `key1`
       /// and its associated value `value1`.
       ///
       /// According to RFC 3986, the set of unreserved characters includes
       ///
       /// `ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"`
       ///
       /// In section 3.4 of the RFC, it further recommends adding `/` and `?` to the list of unescaped characters
       /// for the sake of compatibility with some erroneous implementations, so this routine also allows those
       /// to pass unescaped.

       static var urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
           let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@"    // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
           let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

           var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
           allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)
           return allowed
       }()

   }
   ```