# How do I use performSegue to get to another UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I tried to connect my ViewController to a CollectionViewController with a segue between the two. I control+clicked from the ViewController to the CollectionView Controller and selected the 'show detail' segue, and then made a button with this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("ViewController loaded")
}

@IBAction func EditCharacterSetPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewSegue", sender: self)
}
```

When I press the button in the simulator, it gives me this error message:

[image: unrecognized selector sent to instance]

How do I fix this? Does it have something to do with these other warnings about my CollectionView?:

[image: prototype collection view cells must have reuse identifiers]

I have an Identifier, so that's not the problem:

[image: Storyboard segue - Identifier: CollectionViewSegue]

Comment: have you set the segue identifier ?

Comment: ou are using custom cell but have not set their re use identifier ?

Comment: show your cellForRow method ...

Comment: As jawadAli says, click on the "segue" (the line between your controllers) and provide a name - otherwise xcode errors out as it did. Those two warnings are saying, that xcode is not reusing a cell, but is creating new one each time one is generated (you can name your cell in storyboard)

Comment: This is already answered. Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50406696/4776634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Problem was, he had non-existent IBAction connected to his button.

It seems like your segue does not have an identifier in your storyboard. Based on your code, it should be

```
CollectionViewSegue
```

[image: segue-name]

Regarding your collection view cells. If I recall correctly (did objective-c couple of years back) xcode is creating instances of new Cell and not re-using any of the existing, because you don't have prototype cells defined.

You can (and should) create a cell (either in storyboard, or purely in code), set an identifier to that cell and reuse it in your table view controllers (or in this case in your collection view).

I guess you are just starting with the development, so I would suggest to go through couple of tutorials (e.g. http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/)

Comment: I was following a tutorial for the segue, and I got confused because I do have an identifier. The only thing I did differently would be using a CollectionViewContoller instead of a regular ViewController.

Comment: Just to be clear, your segue is from UIViewController, to the CollectionViewController, correct?

Comment: One more thing, you don't actually have to create ibaction if you want to just transition to other controller - if you ctrl+click and drag from button to the CollectionViewController, storyboard creates the segue for you

Comment: I tried what you said Yanchi, but it just made a segue, it didn't connect the button to it.

Comment: Here are two screenshots -
first segue - controller to controller:
https://imgur.com/a/FHPuYxh

second segue - button to controller:
https://imgur.com/a/EtH7O6u

When you click on your segue - does entire controller highlight (as in screenshot one), or does just the button highlight?

You want the latter - you need to click on the button, then press ctrl+click and drag it over to the collection view controller

Comment: The button highlights. I'm pretty sure I need some code in my ViewController.swift to do the change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214769/discussion-between-yanchi-and-liam).